# System.InsufficientExecutionStackException

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have searched thoroughly this problem I am having (including this website) with no success. I would appreciate any help.

I implemented some code from a previous MVC application to a newer application, which basically contains some views, controllers and models.

In my .ascx view, I use the following code:

```
Html.RenderAction("FieldEdit", "DynamicForms", new { field = field, area = "Adendadora" });
```

This is where the exception appears: "Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can  happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much disk space."

And my action goes like this:

```
    public ActionResult FieldEdit(DynamicUI field)
    {
        if (field.FieldType == DynamicUITypes.Form)
        {
            return PartialView("DynamicGroupFields", field);                
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("DynamicField", field);
        }
    }
```

This View calls that method many times in order to create a dynamic form. The controller action is called via Ajax and the resulting HTML is injected somewhere else on the site.

The thing is, the code remains untouched and it used to work, and now it doesn't. It calls the function successfully many times, until the exception appears.

I'm suspect that it has to be that with this version of the application there is a slighty higher number of stack framecount than with the previous one.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure that neither of those 2 partials contains a `Html.RenderAction()` that calls itself (creating an endless loop)

Comment: Hello Stephen, thank you. Yes, it does contain a section that calls itself, but the loop is not endless, it is quite big though.

Comment: I assume you have misunderstood my comment. If one of your partials contained `Html.RenderAction("FieldEdit", "DynamicForms" ...)`, then that **is** an endless loop. You need to show your partial views

Comment: I may have misunderstood.Yes, that part is called but conditionally, depending on what the object "field" contains. Once again, thank you.

Comment: No one can help unless you show your partial views

Comment: This was strangely fixed when testing on a 64-bit machine instead of a 32-bit one. Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with this error for days. It got fixed by testing on a 64-bit environment.